# Change stored remote host names in terminal application en mass

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, ssh

I have been using the simple hostname to ssh into remote hosts, around 100 systems. There has been a change in configuration of the network that will require FQDNs.

Rather than recreating all my remote system names (stored in terminal and shown when pressing shift-command-k )

Can I edit the stored data to add the domain information to the existing entries?

Comment: I think you need to run one more time as when you add FQDN , it will create a new RSA key fingerprint.

Comment: @Udhy - that's not the question being asked.  The saved host names are found when you hit `Shift-Cmd-K`.  It's like an address book of hosts and has nothing to do with the fingerprint.

Comment: The editors did not like me adding the correct solution directly into the question. While the solution I found that worked is based on a reply to this question it is subtly different which is not obvious unless you are actually trying to do the work.

Comment: Solution
What I did was to get the hosts using "defaults read -app Terminal PermanentServers > foo.sh"

Then I erased the current data "defaults delete -app Terminal PermanentServers"

I edited foo.sh to have lines like:
defaults write -app Terminal PermanentServers -array-add "systema.example.com"
defaults write -app Terminal PermanentServers -array-add "systemb.example.com"

Finally I ran foo.sh, restarted terminal and selected "new remote command" from the Shell dropdown and there were all the systems as FQDNs

Answer (score 2):

The host names are stored in the Terminal settings .plist  in the users `/Library/Preferences` folder:

```
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist
```

#### Edit the .plist

The easiest way to edit a batch of these is by editing the plist with a tool like [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/Download) (free) with the [Binary Plist Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dnicolson.binary-plist#review-details) or your favorite text editor with plist support.<sup>1</sup>  You can also convert the plist to XML (and back to binary) using `plutil`.<sup>2</sup> This will allow you to use *any* text editor like TextEdit that doesn't natively support plist formats.

**Important:  I suggest making a backup copy of the plist before you start editing in case you want to revert back to the original.**

You can find all of your servers in the array under the *PermanentServers* key as shown below.  Simply go in and fix the FDQN as needed.  If the domain suffixes are all the same, a simple Find/Replace should speed through the task.

[image: com.apple.Terminal.plist PermanentServer key]

Save the file and reload Terminal.  For this example, I added the FQDN `.newFQDN` to each entry and restarted Terminal.  Here's the result:

[image: New Remote Connection Updated Results]

#### Alternate Method using `defaults read/write`

You can get the names of the server with the `defaults read` command:

```
$ defaults read -app Terminal PermanentServers

(
    "host1.FQDN",
    "host2.FQDN",
    "host3.FQDN",
    "host4.FQDN"
)
```

You can set your new servers by overwriting that array with a new one as follows:

```
$ defaults write -app Terminal PermanentServers -array '(host1.newFQDN, host2.newFQDN, host3.newFQDN, host4.newFQDN)'
```

You can then reissue the `defaults read` command to check the results.  The upside to this is that you don't need TextWrangler and you can script it.  However, it's difficult to do a large number on the command line so, you'll want to edit it first in a text editor to make sure you have no mistakes.

---

<sup>1</sup> In the first version of this answer, I originally referred to [TextWrangler](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/textwrangler/id404010395?mt=12) as it was a tool I originally used to view/edit plist files.  However, I've been transitioning to VSCode as it's cross platform - macOS, Windows, and even FreeBSD, I discovered a plist plugin that allowed me to finally get rid of TextWrangler, not that it's "bad" in any way; I'm just trying to streamline my dev tools.

<sup>2</sup> To convert a binary plist to XML for editing, issue the command `plutil -convert xml1 foobar.plist`.  Once you're finished editing, save it then convert it back to binary with the command `plutil -convert binary1 foobar.plist`

---

Comment: FYI - TextWrangler is no longer supported, and 32-bit so it won't work on Catalina, but you can use the free version of [BBEdit](https://www.barebones.com) to open `.plist` files without having to convert them to text first. It's by the same company that made TextWrangler and does more than TextWrangler used to do.

Comment: @TJLuoma - good to know.  I haven't gone to Catalina yet because of this 32bit issue.  I've gone over the VS Code and I think I'm sticking with it.

Answer (score 1):

If all you're worried about is being able to `ssh` in, you might not need to change how you connect at all.

You can make aliases in `~/.ssh/config` which refer to other hosts. For example, if you want to be able to do `ssh shortie` instead of `ssh somehostname.plus.fqdn` you would use this in `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host shortie
    HostName somehostname.plus.fqdn
    HostKeyAlias somehostname.plus.fqdn
```

The `HostKeyAlias` tells `ssh` which hostname to use in `~/.ssh/known_hosts` for verifying this connection, so you might want to use the FQDN for that.

I would try that with one of your hosts and see if it works for you. If it does, editing `~/.ssh/config` is certainly the easiest fix, and you can copy it to other computers if you want/need.

You can also assign multiple aliases, too.

The nice thing about doing this as the `ssh` level is that it will work for Terminal.app, iTerm, and any other tools that use ssh.